# When and where is the shipping method in Magento first called?

Tags: php, magento

Where in Magento's PHP source code is the shipping method rates first called? In other words, when is the shipping methods info (flatrate,tablerate,freeshipping) first extracted from the database into PHP code?

I want to remove the default shipping methods and render my own shipping method only for testing in the shopping cart.

Comment: What have you determined so far? Have you stepped through the code with xdebug?

Answer (score 1):

All of Magento's default Shipping Methods pull the rates using its Model from the Database.

For example: if you want to check that from where Flatrate shipping method pull the rates than goto app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php.

This file causes to pull the rates for Flatrate Shipping Method from the Database.